# Sqlalchemy - FastAPI with strawberry Relational Column MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, graphql, strawberry-graphql

I am using FastAPI with strawberry connected to a MySQL database. I have a table called User that is related to a foreign key called IdState with the State table. I would like to know how I can integrate the relationship between my model and the column so that fast api returns all the corresponding State object.

This is my model:
User

```
from conn.db import meta
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Integer, String

usuarios = Table('usuarios', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column('nombre', String(50)),
    Column('correo', String(50)),
    Column('idEstado', Integer, ForeignKey('estados.id'), default=1)
)
```

And this is my model State:

```
from conn.db import meta
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Integer, String

estados = Table('estados', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column('nombre', String(50)),
    Column('descripcion', String(50)),
)
```

and this is my tipping user:

```
import typing
import strawberry
from conn.db import conn
from models.index import usuarios
from models.index import estados
from strawberry.types import Info
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, joinedload

@strawberry.type
class Estado:
    id: int
    nombre: str
    descripcion: str

@strawberry.type
class Usuario:
    id: int
    nombre: str
    correo: str
    idEstado: int
    
@strawberry.type
class Query:
    @strawberry.field
    def usuario(id: int) -> Usuario:
        return conn.execute(usuarios.select().options(joinedload(estados.id)).where(usuarios.c.id == id)).fetchone()
    @strawberry.field
    def usuarios(self) -> typing.List[Usuario]:
        return conn.execute(usuarios.select()).fetchall()

@strawberry.type
class Mutation:
    @strawberry.mutation
    def create_flavour(self, nombre: str, info: Info) -> bool:
        return True
    @strawberry.mutation
    async def create_usuario(self, nombre: str, correo: str, info: Info) -> int:
        usuario =  {
            "nombre": nombre,
            "correo": correo
        }
        result = conn.execute(usuarios.insert(),usuario)
        conn.commit();
        return int(result.inserted_primary_key[0])
    @strawberry.mutation
    def update_usuario(self, id:int, nombre: str, correo: str, idEstado: int, info: Info) -> str:
        result = conn.execute(usuarios.update().where(usuarios.c.id == id), {
            "nombre": nombre,
            "correo": correo,
            "idEstado": idEstado
        })
        print(result. returns_rows)
        conn.commit();
        return str(result.rowcount) + " Row(s) updated"
    @strawberry.mutation
    def delete_usuario(self, id: int) -> bool:
        result = conn.execute(usuarios.delete().where(usuarios.c.id == id))
        return result.rowcount > 0
```

This is the "REQUEST"

```
query Ex{
  usuarios{
    correo,
    nombre,
    idEstado {
      nombre,
      descripcion
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the result what I looking for:

```
{
  "data": {
    "usuarios": [
      {
        "nombre": "levi zepeda acevedooooo update2",
        "correo": "create@gmail.com",
        "idEstado": {
          "nombre": "Activo",
          "descripcion": "Activo"
        }
      },
      {
        "nombre": "levi zepeda 2",
        "correo": "create@gmail.com",
        "idEstado": {
          "nombre": "Activo",
          "descripcion": "Activo"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Pls help :.)